# snowflake to Jira Connection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jira

Could someone please check and let me know if there is any way of loading data from snowflake to Jira.

We have apache airflow system being used. Can we use the same to push the data from snowflake to Jira.

Appreciate eveyones input .

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Hi - have you tried it? What issues are you facing?

Comment: Hi Nick ,  i havnet tried  , i am not sure on the approach

Comment: JIRA cloud has an API that allows you to do all sorts of things in JIRA.  You could create an external function in Snowflake to push data to that API, or use just about any language (like Python, which works nicely with airflow) to push data to JIRA.  Your question likely needs to be more specific, though, if you want any detailed answers.